# How can I properly protect against malicious input with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a chat client that I have built using node.js, and I was wondering what I should do to input messages before sending the to the server?

Comment: Bad guy will just turn javascript off.

Comment: but then nothing would work...

Comment: bad guy would just turn off the validation/sanitation part of your javascript, or just alter the data sent in the request after he jumps through that js hoop.  everything would work just fine, except now he's smuggled bad stuff past your validation

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. You can't stop the client sending 'bad' stuff. Validation and cleaning should be done on the server. You should clean/filter/encode it when displaying it to the client.

Maybe (client side):

```
socket.on('message', function(e) {
  txt = e.data;

  // HTML encode
  txt = txt.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
  txt = txt.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
  txt = txt.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');

  // Or strip tags
  txt = txt.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');

  // Or create a text node
  node = document.createTextNode(txt);
});
```

[You should read this on HTML encoding/escaping.](http://benv.ca/2012/10/4/you-are-probably-misusing-DOM-text-methods/)

Comment: I'm more interested in JavaScript code examples for clearing input...even on the server, since it is node.js

Comment: There are many kinds of clearing input. What's the purpose? SQL? HTML template? CSV?

Comment: The input goes straight through a web socket from the client to all the other clients in the chatroom and is displayed in a <div> element.  Testers were able to hack it so that an alert showed on everyone's screen.

Comment: So you want to HTML encode it before outputting it on the client. You can do that in nodejs or on the client. Replace `<`, `>` and `&` with their HTML entities.

Answer (score 1):

you don't really need to do anything *before* sending it to the server, as far as filtering..you should do filtering/validation server-side.  If you did it client-side people can easily sidestep it.